# KVO keyPathsForValuesAffecting doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, key-value-observing

I have problem with `keyPathsForValuesAffecting<key>` method. I would like to notify observers of `fullName` when `name` or `surname` had changed. But unfortunately observers are not notified.

My code:

class which will be observed:

```
class DependencyTest: NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var fullName: String {
        return name + " " + surname
    }
    @objc var name = ""
    @objc var surname = ""

    class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingFullName() -> Set<NSObject> {
        return ["name" as NSObject, "surname" as NSObject]
    }
}
```

observer ViewController:

```
let dep = DependencyTest()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "dep.fullName", options: .prior, context: nil)

        dep.name = "bob" // Im expecting that `observeValue:` method will be fired
        dep.surname = "gril"

    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?,
                               of object: Any?,
                               change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?,
                               context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        print("" + keyPath!) // not called
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `@objc` on your `keyPathsForValuesAffecting` method so that the KVO machinery can find it using the Objective-C runtime:

```
@objc class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingFullName() -> Set<NSObject> {
    return ["name, "surname"]
}
```

By the way, you can use a property instead, and you can use the `#keyPath` special form to make the compiler help you catch errors:

```
@objc class var keyPathsForValuesAffectingFullName: Set<String> {
    return [#keyPath(name), #keyPath(surname)]
}
```

You should also use `dynamic` on the upstream properties (`name` and `surname`), as Ken Thomases advised.

Here's a full test program (as a macOS command-line program):

```
import Foundation

class DependencyTest: NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var fullName: String {
        return name + " " + surname
    }
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var surname = ""

    @objc class var keyPathsForValuesAffectingFullName: Set<String> {
        return [#keyPath(name), #keyPath(surname)]
    }
}

class Observer: NSObject {
    @objc let dep: DependencyTest

    init(dep: DependencyTest) {
        self.dep = dep
        super.init()
        addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(Observer.dep.fullName), options: .prior, context: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(Observer.dep.fullName), context: nil)
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        print("kvo: \(keyPath!) \(change?[.notificationIsPriorKey] as? Bool ?? false ? "prior" : "post")")
    }
}

let d = DependencyTest()
let o = Observer(dep: d)
d.name = "Robert"
```

Output:

```
kvo: dep.fullName prior
kvo: dep.fullName post
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with a full working test program.

Comment: Note that you also need to apply `@objc` to your `dep` property. If you use `#keyPath` instead of bare strings, the compiler will point out properties that are missing `@objc`.

Comment: perfect! your code in Playground works like a charm! I updated my `dep` with `@objc` and switched `String` with `#keyPath`, but for my VC it still doesn't work, do you have any idea why?
I appreciate that you spend time helping me. 

Answer (score 0):

This should resolve your issue.

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @objc let dep = DependencyTest()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(dep.fullName), options: .new, context: nil)
        self.dep.name = "bob" // Im expecting that `observeValue:` method will be fired
        self.dep.surname = "gril"
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(dep.fullName))
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        print("" + keyPath!) // not called
        print("Full Name = ", dep.fullName)
    }
}

 class DependencyTest: NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var fullName: String = ""
    var name = "" {
        didSet {
            fullName = name + " " + surname
        }
    }
    var surname = "" {
        didSet {
            fullName = name + " " + surname
        }
    }
}
```

The variable run as a function will not be observable, you have to set an actual value. Also remember to remove the observers since this is not a native swift function it will not deinit and could hold your VC into memory after to you dismiss it.

Comment: Of course :) I know that there is couple more ways to achieve the same result, but for me crucial is to use `keyPathsForValuesAffecting<key>` method

Answer (score 0):

The `name` and `surname` properties both need to be `@objc dynamic`, too. Because of your `keyPathsForValuesAffectingFullName` method, KVO observes them when `fullName` is observed. `@objc` is necessary to allow them to be observed. `dynamic` is necessary to make Swift actually call the setter (which is what KVO hooks into) each time they're set, rather than inlining it and just setting the backing instance variable.

Comment: I also tried with `name` and `surname` as `@objc dynamic`... wont work still ;/

Comment: You've verified that your `viewDidLoad` is called?